# CakePHP Paginating Database Views with CRUD Plugin

Tags: cakephp, pagination, crud

**Aim**

Using Cake2.x and the CRUD plugin I need to query and paginate two distinct models

**Approach**

I've written a database view in a model file which performs a Union on the two models I wish to combine and paginate:

```
App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('CakeLog', 'Log');

class Search extends AppModel {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $connection = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
        $return = $connection->execute("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `search` AS
            SELECT Post.id, 'post' AS `type` FROM `posts` AS `Post` 
            UNION 
            SELECT Product.id, 'product' AS `type`  FROM `products` AS `Product`");

        $return = ($return == true)?'Search View created successfully on '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s'):$return;
        CakeLog::write('search', $return);
    }

    public $useTable = 'search';// This model does not use a database table
    public $primaryKey = 'id'; // Define primary key
    public $useDbConfig = 'default'; // Define db
```

**Problem**

I don't seem to be able to paginate the db view, this is what I am doing in my Users controller:

```
$this->loadModel('Search'); // executes the database view SQL
return $this->Crud->execute();
```

However all this does is paginate the User model and not my view. So it seems that I am missing a key step somewhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this is what I am doing in my Users controller:
>
> ```
> $this->loadModel('Search'); // executes the database view SQL
> ```

Calling `loadModel` does not modify the table Crud is going to use - it only makes the model `Search` available in the controller action.

### Change the `modelClass` property

The Crud Index action only calls `paginate` - which in the users controller, by default, is going to paginate the `User` model. To paginate a different table - the simplest method is to set the [modelClass property](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.next/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L269-L277) to that model name:

```
$this->modelClass = 'Search';
$this->Crud->execute();
```

Crud should then paginate the `Search` model.

Comment: Thanks, I tried as you suggested but it still paginates the User model: in my controller - $this->modelClass = 'Search'; $this->Crud->execute();

Comment: I got this working by creating a Search controller, then calling the pagination there rather than in the Users controller - works nicely. TY